# Orientation and integration of differential forms

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms

I have a question about using orientation in the integration of differential forms on a manifold $M$. I have seen two different "versions" of integration. Sorry if this is a little long.

One, as seen in Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*, has to do with integration on chains. To keep things simple, we can look at integrating what he calls a "$k$-dimensional cell"; let's label it $\sigma$. It is given by a triple $\sigma=(D,f,\text{Or})$ consisting

1. a convex polyhedron $D\subset\mathbb{R}^k$,
2. a differentiable map $f\colon D\rightarrow M$, and
3. an orientation on $\mathbb{R}^k$, denoted by $\text{Or}$.

The integral of a $k$-form $\omega$ on $\sigma$ is then defined by
$$\int_\sigma\omega=\int_D f^*\omega.$$

There is no mention of orienting $M$ at all here; instead the orientation seems is given in $\mathbb{R}^k$. So, basically what we do (I hope I'm right) is pull back the form $\omega$ into something that is written in the form of $g(x)\,dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_k$. So if we give the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^k$ positive orientation, then we simply take a normal Riemann integral of $g(x)\,dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n$; if we gave the standard basis negative orientation then we would have the same integral but with a negative value.

What's interesting here to me is how the orientation is given in $\mathbb{R}^k$, not on the manifold itself. So, for example, if I integrate the $1$-form $dx\wedge dy$ on the upper hemisphere of the sphere $S^2$ (seen as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3)$, one way to do this would be to paramaterize the region with a polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the standard orientation) via
$$f(u,v)=(\cos u\sin v,\sin u\sin v,\cos v),$$
where $u\in(0,2\pi)$ and $v\in(0,\pi/2)$. If you evaluate all of the pullbacks, etc., you get that the integral of this form is $-\pi$.

On the other hand, if you orient the upper hemisphere itself, say with an "upward" pointing unit normal, you would expect to get $\pi$ as the answer. So it seems like what I need to do get $\pi$ is to reverse the orientation on $\mathbb{R}^2$, if we're looking at Arnold's definition.

This whole operation then seems a little awkward. My question, then is, how does this relate to the usual definition of integration on an oriented manifold? To me, it seems like any form $\omega$ on $M$ is already been fixed, after all, it just eats in tangent vectors and spits out a number. If a positively oriented chart is used, then we would get $\pi$. Is this correct? I feel like I'm just confused in general about how Arnold doesn't even orient the manifold but instead orients $\mathbb{R}^n$, while in other places the orientation of the manifold (and I guess $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well) also matters.

Comment: The integral as described by Arnold, using an orientation Or on $\mathbb R^k$, should agree with the integral that "you would expect", using an orientation on $D$, if those two orientations match via $f$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So, basically, I would have to check that the pullback map has positive determinant?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to orient $M$ for this operation. Think about it as the specialization of the following scenario. $N$ an oriented differentiable manifold, $D \subset N$ an open subset and $M$ a differentiable manifold.Let $F:D \to M$ be a differential map and $\omega$ a differential form on $M$.  Endow $D$ with the orientation given by $N$ then the following integral is well defined
$$\int_D F^{*}\omega$$

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, are you basically saying that the choice of an orientation in $\mathbb{R}^k$ (in Arnold's sense) is implicitly giving an orientation to $M$? If that is the case, then it seems like we can integrate on non-oriented manifolds. Is that right?

Comment: You did not understand me correctly. You don't need any orientation on $M$ to integrate $F^* \omega$ on $D$. You can integrate the pullback of differential forms on $M$ even if $M$ does not have an orientation. Generally you can integrate stuff on non orientable manifolds but that's a completely different story.

Comment: Okay, so you can integrate chains by pulling it back without any orientation on $M$ (but there is an orientation on $\mathbb{R}^k$, which can change the sign). Stokes theorem would still work for that. But if you want to integrate the entire manifold $M$ you would need an orientation?

Comment: In the regular sense of integration you need orientation if you want to integrate a subspace that is covered by more than one chart.